# How to bring previous page specific text on next page 

Tags: php, html

I have 2 pages of html: a.html & b.html.

- a.html contains text "hello" and a link to b.html.
- When I click the link to b.html, I want the "hello" text to also come on specific place in the b.html page.

How can i do this? Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To bring it along, you'll need to pass it somehow.  It could be something you keep in an input element on the screen, then when you submit it (as a form) it will be available as a $_REQUEST element.  You could also do this by putting your desired welcome message in a hidden element and submitting it in the same manner.

Alternatively, you could put the value you want in a URL string manually.  For example, the link in a.html to go to b.html could be called by:

```
<a href="b.html?welcome=welcome%20to%20the%20show">
```

Doing things on the URL string is more PHP than html, and if your server's not setup correctly you may not be able to get values from the URL string in an HTML document.  So, in that case it's probably easier just to make it a .php file.  Again, not that it can't be done, but it might not be setup to work that way by default.

Answer (score 0):

.html pages are static, so you'd have to copy the desired text manually into the second page.

If you want to do it via PHP, then the simplest way is to put the common text into a file, like:

```
my_html.html:

<p>This is the common text which should be included in both pages</p>
```

and

```
a.php:

... lots of stuff ...
<?php include('my_html.html'); ?>
... more stuff ...
```

and

```
b.php:

... other stuff ...
<?php include('my_html.html'); ?>
... more other stuff ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to "include" some common text between multiple pages.  If you're limited to client-side functionality, it's possible to do this by writing some Javascript to populate an HTML element with a string via DOM, and then include that javascript on both pages.  Both HTML pages would have to define the target element.

If you have server-side technology flexibility, I would suggest you look at PHP.  Implement both pages as .php pages, and use `include()` to include a common file (e.g. common.php) in both pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php sessions and store the text there so e.g.
**a.html**

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['session_name']="Hello";
        echo $_SESSION['session_name'];
    ?>
```

**b.html**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $session['session_name'];
?>
```

A session is more or less a cookie and what you are doing here is storing the string "Hello" in a cookie name "session_name". You can then display the cookies content by using the php echo command :)